# Xpages Scoped variable lost opening next page

Tags: variables, xpages, session-scope

I'm transitioning a corporate web page  into a new xpage platform. It consists of a number of department-specific databases each with their separate ACL's with the old forms and docs, and one new xpage db front end presenting data from across the other db's read only. The content is regulations and resources for the rest of the organization to relate to.

The design consists of just a few custom controls which collects data sources dynamically via properties on the various department specific xpages. So like 30 xpages collecting data from separate db's utilizing the same handful of cc's

My scoped variable issue is related to my  cc_dataViewLocal . This dataView presents the documents from the corresponding views in the source db's. To let the user know their present location in the application I pull in the name of the current view  and display the name above the Data View as a headline on the DataView xpage:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" styleClass="ksHeading2">

<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("dataView1").getData  ().getView()
 }]]></xp:this.value>

</xp:text>
```

All documents from all databases are presented using the same documentDisplay xpage with a dynamic document data source. Thus this xpage does not have any properties but is referenced trough the data view xpage:

```
<xe:dataView id="dataView1" collapsibleCategory="false"

rows="50" style="font-size:8pt" rowStyle="font-size:8pt"

collapsibleDetail="true" pageName="/**ks_documentDisplay.xsp**"

var="rowHandle">
```

--

When I open a document from the data view in documentDisplay.xsp I want the same headline/name of the original view displayed there as well.  To make that happen I try to catch the view name in a scoped variable in an afterPageLoad event in the data view xpage, to redisplay it on the documentDisplay xpage.

```
<xp:this.afterPageLoad>

<xp:setValue binding="#{sessionScope.ksView}">

<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent   
 ("computedField1").value}]]  ></xp:this.value>

</xp:setValue>

</xp:this.afterPageLoad>
```

After all the view name is not part of the document data source, and I have no other handle to the parent view at this point as I can see.

--

When I display the scoped variable on the dataView xpage in a computed field it works fine:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2"

styleClass="ksHeading1" value="#{sessionScope.ksView}">
```

However, when I try to display the same session variable in the documentDispay xpage using the same computed field coding it turns up empty. Like the sessionVariable is lost to the next xpage?

I started out with a viewScope, and tried both request and session with same results. What am I missing??

Any input greatly appreciated! Including workarounds but would like to get a grip on the scoped variables...:-)

Regards to all who read this somewhat long post and thanks in advance!

Vidar Solevag

Comment: Is the "data view xpage" (or custom control) somehow also loaded on the "documentDisplay" Xpage? I think that "afterPageLoad" part code is fired inside the "documentDisplay" Xpage and therefore emptying the sessionScope variable. SessionScope variables are not lost when navigating to another page.

Comment: I second what @Ferry said. I think you are overwriting the sessionScope variable.  Maybe change it so that you only set the value if it is currently null.

Comment: Vidar, no need to apologize for your question length. It helps explain your issue sufficiently. Often questions don't give enough info.

Comment: Thanks for your input both of you @Ferry and @Steve! Could the fact that data is collected from another database than the one in which the two xpages and the cc's reside be a problem?   The variable need to be able to change when the user enters another of the dataView xpages.  I'm thinking if the data exchange from different databases wipes the variables are Managed Beans a way to go? Get a user bean tracking the last visited Views?

Comment: No, sessionScoped variables will always be there until some code resets it or after a timeout of 30mins. SessionScoped variables are not shared accros multiple Xpage nsf's.Try moving the code in the afterPageLoad event to onClientLoad.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction. The problem clearly was I wiped the sessionScope in some way or other, exactly how I still don't know.

But as often is the case the solution was to do something else to get the same thing done...

**What I found not to work:**
-Moving the event to onClientLoad didn't work it threw an exception "cannot handle". In addition my original approach afterPageLoad did't really work either as it didn't update properly as other dataViews were chosen via Navigator on the page. Also setting the variable via the "Set" option on the simpleAction list turned out to be a problem. I got several "Not allowed to set the value of a read only computed expression"

**What I did that worked:**
-I set the value not by "Set"Simple action but by "Excecute script" and code
sessionScope.ksView=context.getSubmittedValue(). This in the onClick event in  Navigator that selects which Dataview  to display On the DataView xpage Then the SessionScope remains alive all the way into the documentDisplay xpage and until a different  Dataview  is selected back in the Nav back on the DataView xpage.

Now using the same sessionScope as the viewName property on the xpage I also set the sessionScope initially on afterPageLoad to have a default value when page is first opened...

So thanks again, a lot of headbanging into the wall here but that's what you learn from I guess :-))